# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to extract the number after NUMERO, it worked for one sentence, but I have a dataframe contains more sentences, so i used a loop but it dosn't work :

for one sentence :

```py
b="jghjghjgh : 1 hjggjhgjh: 0  NUMERO : 1544kkk454 jgjhjgjgjdgstrythghgjh "   
m = re.search('NUMERO : (\S+)', b , re.IGNORECASE)
m.group(1)
```

Using the loop

```py
for f in identifiant["det"] :
        f=repr(f)
        m = re.search('NUMERO : (\S+)', f, re.IGNORECASE)
        m.group(1)
```

i got this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-136-1f5f32a53ddb>", line 4, in <module>
    m.group(1)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Any hints please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your error means that `m` is `None`, which happens when the regex search doesn't find anything.

Your first code example works. In your second example the error suggests that your regex search was unsuccessful, but since we don't know what your `identifiant` variable holds, we can't say why.

To check what's wrong, add a debug line:

```
for f in identifiant["det"] :
    f=repr(f)
    m = re.search('NUMERO : (\S+)', f, re.IGNORECASE)
    if not m:
        print(f)
```

Comment: Identifiant is a dataframe holds sentences like "jghjghjgh : 1 hjggjhgjh: 0  NUMERO : 1544kkk454 jgjhjgjgjdgstrythghgjh "

Comment: add `print(f)` before re.search() for debugging

Comment: I did, i don't know what's the problem yet

Comment: Can you share it, please? The exact line(s) you run `re.search()` on?

Comment: [ "jghjghjgh : 1 hjggjhgjh: 0 NUMERO : 1544kkk454 jgjhjgjgjdgstrythghgjh " , ["aaa : 02 dassed : 06 NUMERO : 1544kkk454 fsfzfzf fsdfdsf fsfds", "jfsdf fdsfdff NUMERO : 1544kkk454", "fsdfds gdfg  NUMERO : 1111114565 hjgjhg" ] it's a list like this, it was a dataframe and i convert it to a list